# React Native, When converting a String to a Date, the result is different when in Debug mode

Tags: react-native

I want to convert the String to a date and compare it to the current one.

When I saw the results after coding `Debug JS Remotely`, it worked.

However, if Debug JS is stopped and then executed, the result will be changed to `invalid Date`.

How can I produce consistent results?

```
const checkNotice = async () => {
  const noticeStart = new Date('2019-04-30 00:01:02');
  const noticeEnd = new Date('2019-10-07 23:59:59');
  const now = new Date();
  if (now > noticeStart && now < noticeEnd) {
    return {
      NoticeStart: noticeStart,
      NoticeEnd: noticeEnd,
    };
  }
  return false;
};
```

When this code is in Debug mode
`noticeStart` and `noticeEnd` are replaced by Date.
However, if stop Debug mode, it will change to `invalid Date` and will always return `false`.

Everything else is the same.
Only the debug mode is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two `Date` object, you can try doing

`now.getTime() > noticeStart.getTime() && now.getTime() < noticeEnd.getTime()`

Maybe this is because the behavior is different between the web browser JS interpreter and React Native JSCore. Have you looked at the issued on React-Native repository? ^^

Comment: The result of the `new Date (string)` before the comparison, regardless of the comparison, is returned as an `invalid Date`.
So `getTime ()` will get the `Nan`.

Comment: JS interpreter and React Native JSCore. I found your answer to be different.
I searched for two keywords and found the answer.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/782